# Why is my user input not called when I run this function?

Tags: python

I'm super new to python and am working on a project for school. I am trying to open up a csv file to use in later functions. When I run my code, my terminal does not prompt me for an input at all. What am I missing? This works if I just remove the "def get_input_descriptor" but my project requires that I define this as a function.

```
def main():
    def get_input_descriptor():
        while True:
            filename= input("Enter a file name: ")
            try:
                file = open(filename,newline = '')
                break
            except IOError:
                print("Bad file name, try again")
                continue
    
                    
    def get_data_list(filename):
        filedata = csv.DictReader(file)
        column = input("Which Column: ")
        if column == 1:
            columnread = "Open"
        elif column == 2:
            columnread = "High"
        elif column == 3:
            columnread = "Low"
        elif column == 4:
            columnread = "Close"
        elif column == 5:
            columnread = "Volume"
        elif columnread == 6:
            columnread = "Adj Close"
        datalist = []
        for row in filedata:
            print(row["Date"],row[columnread])
main()
```

Comment: Your main only contains function definitions. You need to call those functions to do anything

Comment: Some may consider a bad things to get a break inside a while True loop when you can do otherwise, especially when the code grows.
As @scrappedcola said, you actually never call your function, only define it. 
Why do you ask for a filename on  get_data_list but use file instead ? This will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read this page first before asking homework related questions [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

However... In Python defining a function with `def` will only run that code if the function gets called e.g. `get_input_descriptor()`  When you remove the `def get_input_descriptor():` bit the code is no longer "locked" in a function and is now part of the main method an so can run.

If you NEED to make this a separate function then you would move it above the main method code and then call the function `get_input_descriptor()` from within the main method

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually making a call to the `get_data_list` function.

When you use the `def` keyword in python, that means you are defining a function that you later wish to call. So you're just setting it up so you can use it later.

You've already done this with the `main` function, you use `def main():` at the start, which sets it up, then later you call `main()` to actually run the function.

So what you're doing here is setting up a function called `main`, then you call that function later. When you call it, it sets up two more functions `get_input_descriptor` and `get_data_list`, but neither of them actually get called. I'm guessing, but you probably want something that looks more like this

```
def get_input_descriptor():
    while True:
        filename= input("Enter a file name: ")
        try:
            file = open(filename,newline = '')
            break
        except IOError:
            print("Bad file name, try again")
            continue

                
def get_data_list(filename):
    filedata = csv.DictReader(file)
    column = input("Which Column: ")
    if column == 1:
        columnread = "Open"
    elif column == 2:
        columnread = "High"
    elif column == 3:
        columnread = "Low"
    elif column == 4:
        columnread = "Close"
    elif column == 5:
        columnread = "Volume"
    elif columnread == 6:
        columnread = "Adj Close"
    datalist = []
    for row in filedata:
        print(row["Date"],row[columnread])

def main():
     get_input_descriptor()
     get_data_list(filename)

main()
```

There are a few other problems in your code, but I think you can work them out if you get passed this problem.